# Emacs - How to automate formatting of python code?

Tags: python-2.7, emacs, formatting

Assuming the code is pasted in emacs, as shown below

```
# x = 'global x'                                                                                                                                                                                           

def test(z):                                                                                                                                                                                               
    global x # variable from global namespace                                                                                                                                                              
    x = 'local x'                                                                                                                                                                                          
    # x = 'local x'                                                                                                                                                                                        
    # print(y)                                                                                                                                                                                             

                   print(x)                                                                                                                                                                                
                      print(z)                                                                                                                                                                             


                      # test('local z')                                                                                                                                                                    
                      # print(x)                                                                                                                                                                           

                      def outer():                                                                                                                                                                         

                             x = 'outer x'                                                                                                                                                                 

                                def inner():                                                                                                                                                               
                                          nonlocal x # local variables of enclosing function                                                                                                               
                                                x = 'inner x'                                                                                                                                              
                                                      print(x)                                                                                                                                             

                                                         inner()                                                                                                                                           
                                                            print(x)
```

`.emacs` file has following content

```
(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(custom-enabled-themes (quote (deeper-blue))))
(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 )
```

---

**Question:**

As per python indentation rules, what is the best way to automate formatting of python code?

Comment: Please do not post the same question here and at emacs.SE. Choose one or the other. Thx.

Comment: @Drew I removed the query on emacs.SE

Comment: @Dan I pressed `C-h` and then pressed `M-x` and type `indent-region`, but did not see any better.

Comment: is this `python-mode`? what does `C-h m` say?

Comment: Because Python uses syntactic indentation, there's no way in general to automatically format Python code.  There's a tool called `yapf` to try to format Python, and a couple of packages in Melpa to use it from Emacs.

Comment: @sds I did this `(add-to-list 'load-path "/usr/share/emacs/24.5/lisp/progmo des")` and   `(load "python")` in `~/.emacs` Because I see `python.el` in that path.

Comment: How to format the code automatically? Still am stuck